# Rails4 - How to update a view when a table gets updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I get some data from a page abc.html using Ajax and I store it in a table.
Once the data get stored in the table(i.e. commit takes place), I want that data to be updated in the page xyz.html in runtime so that the users can see the updates without having to refresh the page.

I have got the data and updated the data in the table.
But I don't know what to do once the data gets stored in the table.
I believe ajax is required to update the webpage xyz.html.
It would be of great help if someone can point to a resource on what approach to follow to implement it.

--Update--
I am a newbie but I am not asking anyone to write the code for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to look into something like Socket.IO for real-time updating.

http://socket.io/

Basically, socket.io is a javascript library built on top of Node.JS that constantly trolls a servers looking for new activity. This is sort of ajax, but an ajax request is normally prompted by a user (by a button click or scrolling to the bottom of the page, for example).

I'm not gonna write the code for you. If you are new, it's not going to be an easy thing to accomplish. This may seem like a simple feature, but it's actually quite complex.

If you start writing code, and get stuck, come back and ask a question, but no one is going to write this feature for you for free buddy, sorry.

Here is a tutorial on how to write a real-time updating chat-application with Socket.IO. Take some time and get to know how Socket.IO works and you should be able to figure out how to make it work for your needs.

Comment: Could you please share the tutorial?